# Correct use of Boolean modifier?

Tags: modeling

At its simplest, I have two objects. The first is a modified block. Then I add a cylinder, shaped like I want. This is to be joined to one end of the block.

If I move the cylinder into the position that I want, it seems I am getting an automatic union of the two objects. If I select the block to begin the Boolean union sequence, I find that both objects are selected. I cannot separate the two objects to try again.

I have to be doing something wrong, but I’m stuck. Any suggestions?

Oh yes, sorry. I’m using Blender 2.81a.

Regards.

Comment: Do you speak about Boolean modifier https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html , Intersect (boolean) operator, or BoolTool add-on https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/object/bool_tools.html?